# Where are gs-X11 and gs-noX11 on my Mac?

Tags: macos, installation, ghostscript, xquartz, tex

I performed the following steps:

1. Reinstalled macOS **Ventura 13.4** on my system. (I was taken aback to not find `/usr/local/bin/`, but then [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280452/495879) provided relief.)
2. Installed Homebrew. (It is in `/opt` as expected.)
3. Did `brew install --cask xquartz`. This

   - installed `X11/` in `/opt/`,
   - added `XQuartz.app` in `/Applications/`, and
   - created symlinks X11 and X11R6 in `/usr/`, both pointing to `X11/` in `/opt`.
4. Did `brew install --cask mactex`. This resulted in things including:

   - Installed `texlive/` in `/usr/local`.
   - Installed `ghostscript/` in `/opt/Homebrew/Cellar/`.
   - Installed `TeX/` containing TeXShop, etc. in `/Applications/`.

(I have everything updated to the latest at I write. Also, I cross-verified the md5 checksum of `.pkg`.)

Now, when I tried to run LaTeXiT, it greeted me with the following error:

[image]

I went through the `READ ME FIRST.pdf` that came with the applications which mentions:

> Ghostscript installs support files in `/usr/local/share/ghostscript/10.00.0` and a few binaries in `/usr/local/bin`. In particular, it installs `gs-X11` and `gs-noX11` in `/usr/local/bin`, where the first requires X11 and the second does not. Then MacTeX installs a symbolic link `gs` pointing to the first binary if the user’s machine has X11, and to the second binary otherwise. New versions of Ghostscript can be installed over version 10.00 without removing 10.00 first.

This documentation doesn't seem to be updated with the fact that Homebrew's prefix is in `/opt/Homebrew/` for Apple Silicon: `/usr/local/share/` should have been `/opt/Homebrew/Cellar`.

Next, **I still don't have `usr/local/bin`**, wherein to find `gs-X11` and `gs-noX11`. In fact, an `mdfind` or `find` search yields no results for these.

Furthermore, from the [MacTeX website](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html):

> The TeX Live programs `xdvi`, `pdfopen`, and `pdfclose` require X11. In addition, the Ghostscript library `libgs` requires X11 (but notice that `dvisvgm` is the only TeX Live program using it). Ghostscript comes with two binaries, `gs-X11` and `gs-noX11`, where `gs-X11` has support for X11 and `gs-noX11` does not. When Ghostscript is first installed, a symbolic link named `gs` is created in `/usr/local/bin`. If X11 is present, `gs` points to `gs-X11`; otherwise it points to `gs-noX11`. On Arm machines, `gs` points to `gs-X11` only if XQuartz 2.8.0 or higher is present.

**Questions:**

1. Where are `gs-X11`, `gs-noX11`, and the symlink `gs` on my system?
2. How to have everything integrated, so that TeX detects Ghostscript, and LaTeXiT works fine?

---

### Edit:

Some further relevant observations:

1. I confirm that **TeX is working correctly**: `latex file.tex` on the terminal produces `file.dvi` in the same (writeable) directory. However, I also observe another issue (most likely related):
   According to [this TUG post](https://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2004-June/006165.html), I should be having no trouble viewing the generated `file.dvi` using TeXShop, for according to the post, it is just executing `dvips` and `ps2pdf`. (I confirm that `dvips file.ps` and then `ps2pdf file.ps` generate the expected `file.pdf` in the concerned directory.) However, when I open it with TeXShop, it does nothing.
2. **Installing with brew should not be causing any problem** since I checked the md5 checksum of the `mactex-20230314.pkg` that brew fetched, and it matched with what [MacTeX reports](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html).

Comment: Please do not put [SOLVED] in the title, this will not help most search engines. Instead accept one of the answers that happened to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything has been sorted out now by what Richard Koch (author of the TeXShop application) suggested me on email: Changing the following paths in the preferences/settings did the trick:

1. In TeXShop, under the Engine tab, changed the "Distiller (ghostscript)" field to `/opt/homebrew/bin`.
2. In LaTeXiT, under the Typesetting tab, changed
   the "Ghostscript (gs)" field to `/opt/homebrew/bin/gs`, and
   the "ps2pdf" field to `/opt/homebrew/bin/ps2pdf`.

Turns out the problem was that Brew changed the HOMEBREW_PREFIX for Apple Silicon to `/opt/homebrew`, and MacTeX is yet to incorporate this recent change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

See the
[homebrew-gs-x11](https://github.com/johnhcc/homebrew-gs-x11)
project, which says this :

> The Homebrew core Ghostscript formula no longer supports X11, which
> also prevents use of GV (a derivative of Ghostview). I created this
> custom tap to allow users to install these formulae once again, on
> either Mac and Linux systems. First, [install
> Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if necessary.
>
> To install Ghostscript with X11 support:
>
> ```
> brew install johnhcc/gs-x11/ghostscript-x11
> ```
>
> This builds from source and it may take 10 minutes or more to
> complete. Please be patient, even if it seems to be stuck.
>
> Ghostscript will be installed as
> [keg-only](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#what-does-keg-only-mean), meaning
> it will not be linked into `/usr/local` to prevent conflicts with the
> core Ghostscript formula. However you can still access the X11-enabled
> binaries directly at `$(brew --prefix)/opt/ghostscript-x11/bin`.
>
> Similarly, GV can be installed with:
>
> ```
> brew install johnhcc/gs-x11/gv
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working either.

Comment: Here's what I did: 
1.) Ran `brew install johnhcc/gs-x11/ghostscript-x11`.

2.) Ran `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ghostscript-x11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` (as was suggested in the final prompt).

3.) Opened LaTeXit to get the same error.

Comment: A pity that it doesn't work, as the project was last updated only a year ago. Try perhaps to get in touch with the developer.

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391805/need-to-install-ghostscript-to-mac-path) is helpful.

Comment: @harrymac The issue is solved now.